# Can you add comments to tables and other objects in Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: sql, comments, google-cloud-sql

Postgres has the `comment` command: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-comment.html. Does Google Cloud SQL have something similar?

Also Postgres has system tables such as [pg_description](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/catalog-pg-description.html) that allow you to query the comments using SQL. Is there an equivalent in Google Cloud SQL?

Comment: as of March 2017 Postgres is now available in Google Cloud SQL:  https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/

Answer (score 2):

MySQL does support the similar syntax, e.g.

CREATE TABLE t2 (age INT COMMENT "field1 comment", name TEXT COMMENT "field2 comment") COMMENT "table comment";

Please see official doc for more details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html

Please note, this is not Google Cloud SQL specific.